# How to read file by url in node js

Tags: node.js, stream, line-by-line

I using line-by-line module for node js, and I want to set file from url for example now i have this:

```
LineByLineReader     = require('line-by-line'),
  lr                   = new LineByLineReader('file.txt');
```

And i want to

```
LineByLineReader     = require('line-by-line'),
  lr                   = new LineByLineReader('http://test.pl/file.txt');
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can archive that using streams.

The lib you have choosen `line-by-line` support them so you have only to do like so:

- create a readable stream (form a file in the filesystem or from a resource online via http)
- pass the stream to your lib and listen for events

This works, note that you need to require `http` or `https` based on your url, my example is https

```
const http = require('https');
const LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line')

const options = {
  host: 'stackoverflow.com',
  path: '/questions/54251676/how-to-read-file-by-url-in-node-js',
  method: 'GET',
};

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');

  lr = new LineByLineReader(res);


  lr.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('err', err);
  });

  lr.on('line', function (line) {
    console.log('line', line);
  });

  lr.on('end', function () {
    console.log('end');
  });

});
req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log('problem with request', e);
  req.abort();
});
req.end();
```